# Undo/redo image progress

Tags: swift, image, undo, redo

I have a functionality that changes the picture, and there are two cancel/return buttons
i wrote 3 functions for this
add
undo
redo
The problem is that when I press 2 times undo and then redo, my image redo is two steps forward

My code

```
 public var undoHistory: [UIImage] = []
public var redoHistory: [UIImage] = []

public func undoImage() -> UIImage? {
    guard !(undoHistory.count == 1) else {
        return undoHistory.last
    }
    
    if let lastImage = undoHistory.last {
        redoHistory.append(lastImage)
        undoHistory.removeLast()
    }
    return undoHistory.last
}

public func addImageToHistory(_ image: UIImage) {
    undoHistory.append(image)

    guard !redoHistory.isEmpty else {
        return
    }
    redoHistory.removeAll()
}

public func redoImage() -> UIImage? {
    guard !(redoHistory.count == 1) else {
        return redoHistory.last
    }
    
    if let lastImage = redoHistory.last {
        redoHistory.removeLast()
        undoHistory.append(lastImage)
    }
    return redoHistory.last
}
```

Comment: Did you know know that Undo/Redo is built in? If you use the built in feature, it will keep track of the undo stack and the redo stack correctly and you won't have to worry about it.

Comment: @matt how is it built in? can you help me?

Comment: Look up UndoManager.